# I found a beautiful integral $I = \int_{0}^{\infty} e^{-[x] \cdot (1 + \{x\})}\,\mathrm{d}x$

Tags: integration

Where I am wrong in this question?

$$I = \int_{0}^{\infty} e^{-[x] \cdot (1 + \{x\})}\, \mathrm{d}x$$

My work

We'll split this integral into two cases:

- $0 \leq x < 1$
  $$I_1 = \int_{0}^{1} e^{0} \cdot e^{-x}\, \mathrm{d}x$$
  $$I_1 = \int_{0}^{1} e^{-x}\, \mathrm{d}x = -e^{-x} \Big|_{0}^{1} = -e^{-1} + 1$$
- $x \geq 1$:
  In this case, $[x] = 1$ and $\{x\} = x - 1$,
  $$I_2 = \int_{1}^{\infty} e^{-1 \cdot (1 + x - 1)}\, \mathrm{d}x$$
  $$I_2 = \int_{1}^{\infty} e^{-x} dx = -e^{-x} \Big|_{1}^{\infty} = 0 + e^{-1} = e^{-1}$$

$$I = I_1 + I_2 = (-e^{-1} + 1) + e^{-1} = 1$$

So, the solution to the integral is $I = 1$.

Comment: What is $[x]$? Is it the floor function $\lfloor x\rfloor$? If yes, then, it is not true that $\lfloor x\rfloor=1$ for all $x\ge 1$. Instead, $\lfloor x\rfloor=k$ when $k\le x\lt k+1$ where $k$ is an integer.

Comment: Also, the math formatting on this site does not use the `\(...\)` / `\[...\]` format but rather the `$...$` and `$$...$$` format. You can [edit] your question accordingly. [Here](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020/215900) is a big-list/documentation for how to write math on here.

Comment: \begin{align*}
\text{The statement that } \lfloor x \rfloor &= 1 \text{ for all } x \ge 1 \text{ is not true.} \\
\text{The correct statement is that } \lfloor x \rfloor &= k \text{ for all } x \text{ such that } k \le x < k + 1, \text{ where } k \text{ is an integer.}
\end{align*}

Comment: I'm confused. Why is the integrand $e^{-x}$ on $[0,\,1]$? Is $[x]$ supposed to be $x/(1+x)$?

Comment: @J.G.    The integrand $e^-x$
  is on $[0,1]$ because the floor function $⌊x⌋$is equal to $0$ for all $x$ in the interval $[0,1]$. This is because the greatest integer less than or equal to $x$ is always less than or equal to 1 for all $x$ in the interval $[0,1]$

Comment: I don't think you understand the point I'm making. $e^0e^{-x}$ looks less plausible than $e^{-0\cdot(1+x)}=e^{-0}=1$.

Comment: In the strongest sense, what you have shown is that $\int_0^\infty e^{-x}\,\mathrm{d}x = 1$.  This is true, but it has nothing to do with your initial integral, because in each case, you erroneously simplify the integrand.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$$\eqalign{
  &  * {\text{Let's determine}}: - \left\lfloor x \right\rfloor \left( {1 + \left\{ x \right\}} \right) =  - \left\lfloor x \right\rfloor \left( {1 + x - \left\lfloor x \right\rfloor } \right){\text{ since}}:\left\{ x \right\} = x - \left\lfloor x \right\rfloor   \cr 
  & 0 < x < 1 \Rightarrow  - \left\lfloor x \right\rfloor \left( {1 + x - \left\lfloor x \right\rfloor } \right) = 0  \cr 
  & n \leqslant x < n + 1\left( {n > 1} \right) \Rightarrow \left\lfloor x \right\rfloor  = n,1 - \left\lfloor x \right\rfloor  = 1 - n \Rightarrow  - \left\lfloor x \right\rfloor \left( {1 + x - \left\lfloor x \right\rfloor } \right) =  - n\left( {1 - n + x} \right)  \cr 
  &  =  - nx + {n^2} - n  \cr 
  &  \Rightarrow I = \int\limits_0^1 {{e^0}dx}  + \sum\limits_{n = 1}^\infty  {\int\limits_n^{n + 1} {{e^{ - nx + {n^2} - n}}dx} }  = 1 + \sum\limits_{n = 1}^\infty  {\int\limits_n^{n + 1} {{e^{ - nx + {n^2} - n}}dx} }   \cr 
  &  = 1 + \sum\limits_{n = 1}^\infty  {{e^{{n^2} - n}}\left. {\left( { - \frac{{{e^{ - nx}}}}{n}} \right)} \right|} _n^{n + 1} = 1 + \sum\limits_{n = 1}^\infty  {{e^{{n^2} - n}}} \frac{{{e^{ - {n^2} - n}}\left( {{e^n} - 1} \right)}}{n} = 1 + \sum\limits_{n = 1}^\infty  {\frac{{{e^{ - 2n}}\left( {{e^n} - 1} \right)}}{n}}   \cr 
  &  = 1 + \sum\limits_{n = 1}^\infty  {\frac{{{e^{ - n}} - {e^{ - 2n}}}}{n}}   \cr 
  &  * {\text{Known}}:\sum\limits_{n = 1}^\infty  {\frac{{{x^n}}}{n} =  - \ln \left( {1 - x} \right)}  \Rightarrow {\text{let}}:x = {e^{ - 1}},x = {e^{ - 2}}  \cr 
  &  \Rightarrow I = 1 + \sum\limits_{n = 1}^\infty  {\frac{{{e^{ - n}} - {e^{ - 2n}}}}{n}}  = 1 - \ln \left( {1 - {e^{ - 1}}} \right) + \ln \left( {1 - {e^{ - 2}}} \right)  \cr 
  &  = 1 - \ln \left( {1 - \frac{1}{e}} \right) + \ln \left( {1 - \frac{1}{{{e^2}}}} \right) = 1 - \ln \left( {\frac{{e - 1}}{e}} \right) + \ln \left( {\frac{{{e^2} - 1}}{{{e^2}}}} \right) = \ln \left( {e + 1} \right) \cr} $$